# Footnote <sub> text collapsed into a single line in Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, mobile-safari

I spotted this weird-looking text on the mobile site:

[image]

I'm using Safari in iOS 8.3 (12F70) on an iPhone 5S. I get the same problem in the iOS Simulator, running iOS 8.3 (12F69).

The question comes [from SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90675/3567), and this is the markup which caused the bug:

```
<sub>
**#** Give or take an instance or two where he's unworthy, and then proves that he's worthy after all.

**^** I don't mean making Thor unworthy, by doing something like, corrupting him or something, but can someone **physically** stop Thor from grabbing his hammer, without holding his arms or anything?
</sub>
```

No idea what combination of HTML weirdness caused this.

Comment: Can you confirm if the exact same effect happens on both lines [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233794/158100)?

Comment: @rene Interesting, it doesn’t. The second paragraph in the `<sub>` is rendered as normal text. I wonder if maybe it’s an SFF-specific bug, or perhaps a bug that got squashed in the new designs? (SFF is still on the old system)

Comment: Ok, adding two spaces at the end of the lines fixes this anomaly in this case,  Still a bug but makes it easier for a dev to fix. It is not an SFF specific bug, as it reproduces here on MSE as well.

Comment: Possibly related bug on SFF Meta: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6934/3567

Comment: FWIW This happens to like [most](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60118/21267) [of](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81718/21267) [my](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67809/21267) [posts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/70595/21267) because that's the formatting I often use... Never thought to raise it as a bug though, thanks for raising it! :)